# Implementing class used in Constructor Interface parameter

Tags: java

```
public interface Photo {
}

class PlacePhoto implements Photo{}

class PlaceDetail {
  public PlaceDetail(List<Photo> photos)
}

List<PlacePhoto> placePhotos = new ArrayList<PlacePhoto>();
```

The below line fails type checking: expected argument (`List<Photo>`) cannot be applied to actual (`List<PlacePhoto>`)

```
PlaceDetail placeDetail = new PlaceDetail(placePhotos);
```

If PlacePhoto implements Photo, why can I not use it for a Photo parameter?

Comment: See the answer for why it doesn't work and the question for the solution.

Comment: @shmosel Looks like inheritance is more appropriate than interface implementation in this case. Thanks.